# Angular не получается поменять дату в шаблоне

Tags: angularjs, angular2, angular, angular4

При клике не кнопке должна меняться дата в шапке сайта на следующую, в консоли дата меняется а в шаблоне почему то нет=(

Если я просто строковую переменную меняю при клике то все ок а дата только в консоли, я новичок помогите разобраться

компонент

```
export class TopperComponent implements OnInit {

  topDate: any  = new Date();
  test: any;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.topDate);
  }

  nextTopDate(){
    this.topDate.setDate(this.topDate.getDate() + 1);
    console.log(this.topDate);
  }
}
```

код HTML

```
<div class="topper">
  <div class="topper-btns">
    <button type="button" class="main-menu" title="Меню"></button>
    <button type="button" class="prev-date" title="Предыдущая дата"></button>
    <button type="button" class="next-date" title="Следующая дата" (click)="nextTopDate()"></button>
    <button type="button" class="today-ico" title="Сегодня"><span>13</span></button>
    <button type="button" class="add-task" title="Добавить задачу"></button>
  </div>

  <div class="top-date" >{{topDate | topDatePipe }}</div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `this.topDate.setDate(this.topDate.getDate() + 1); this.topDate = new Date(this.topDate);` - изменяйте ссылку

Comment: спасибо сработало=)